# How to change / delete product short description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, excerpt, terms

How to change / delete product short description in Woocommerce

I use

```
$short_desc = $post->post_excerpt;
```

to read the property but I cant change it with

```
 wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, $post->post_excerpt, 'new excerpt');
```

Comment: I guess you need to expand your code. Otherwise we can't tell you what might be wrong. Just `wp_set_object_terms` doesn't tell us anything, when we don't know how exactly you are using it. In what function, with what parameters, retrieved from where? Please **update your question** accordingly. Many thanks

Comment: Looking at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms I'm wondering what exactly are you trying to do with this function?

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Th function [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) will not work to set post object properties.

To add/update/delete product short description **there is mainly 2 ways**:

1) **the WordPress way** from a **post ID** using [`wp_update_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) function this way:

```
$product_id = $post->ID; // or get_the_id() or $product->get_id() (when $product is available);

// The product short description (for testing)
$new_short_description = "<strong>Here</strong> is is the product short description content."

// Add/Update/delete the product short description
wp_update_post( array('ID' => $product_id, 'post_excerpt' => $new_short_description ) );
```

2) **The WooCommerce way** from the **`WC_product` Object** using [`set_short_description()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_set_short_description):

```
// Optional: get the WC_product Object instance from the post ID
$product_id = $post->ID; // or get_the_id()
$product    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// The product short description (for testing)
$new_short_description = "<strong>Here</strong> is is the product short description content."

$product->set_short_description( $new_short_description ); // Add/Set the new short description
$product->save(); // Store changes in database
```

---

To **delete** the product description you will set an **empty string**.

---

Related: [How to programmatically grab the product description in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022415/how-to-programmatically-get-the-product-description-in-woocommerce/56022850#56022850)

Answer (score 2):

You should have the `$product` global available to you, which lets you call [set_short_description](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_set_short_description) and then [save](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_save) to store the changes:

```
$product->set_short_description('some description');
$product->save();
```

Comment: can I use $post instead of $product ?